# An "obvious" probability lemma about random words

Tags: pr.probability, inequalities

Fix some positive integers $p,n,k$.  Let $w$ be chosen uniformly at random from $[k]^n$ (the set of $n$ length words/sequences where each entry is in $\{1,\ldots,k\}$). Let $A_i$ be the event that $w_r=i$ for at least $p$ values of $r$.  Can one prove that, for all $s$, $$\Pr\left(\bigwedge_{i=1}^{s-1} A_i\ \large|\ A_s^c\right)\ge \Pr\left(\bigwedge_{i=1}^{s-1} A_i\right).$$  In other words, if we know some letter appears few times, is it more likely that other letters appear many times?  Intuitively it seems like this result must be true, but I don't have a good argument to prove it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The property in question is a special case (with the probabilities of all the $k$ outcomes equal to one another) of the known $NA$ (negative association) property of the multinomial distribution; see e.g. [this sentence in the bottom paragraph on page 5](https://arxiv.org/abs/1803.09663v1):

> $NA$ property of multinomial distributions can be seen from Condition $N$, since it is the conditional distribution of independent Poisson random variables given their sum.

---

Indeed, for each $i\in[k]:=\{1,\dots,k\}$, let $N_i$ denote the number of times the letter $i$ appears in the random word of length $n$. Then $(N_1,\dots,N_k)$ has the $k$-nomial distribution with parameters $n,1/k,\dots,1/k$, and the inequality in question can be written as 
$$P(N_1\ge p,\dots,N_s\ge p)\le P(N_1\ge p,\dots,N_{s-1}\ge p)P(N_s\ge p)$$
or, equivalently, as 
$$Cov\,\big(f(N_1,\dots,N_{s-1}),g(N_s,\dots,N_k)\big)\le0,$$
where $f$ and $g$ are the functions (nondecreasing in each argument) given by formulas
$$f(n_1,\dots,n_{s-1}):=1_{n_1\ge p,\dots,n_{s-1}\ge p}$$
and 
$$g(n_s,\dots,n_k):=1_{n_s\ge p}\,;$$
cf. Definition 2.1 of $NA$ in the linked paper.

Answer (score 2):

I think it is easier if you rewrite your inequality as 
\begin{align} 
 & P( \bigcap_{i=1}^{s-1}A_i ) - P ( \bigcap_{i=1}^{s-1}A_i \cap A_s) \geq  P(\bigcap_{i=1}^{s-1}A_i)(1-P(A_s)) \\ 
 & \iff P(A_s) \geq P(A_s | \bigcap_{i=1}^{s-1}A_i).
\end{align}
Now let $\{X_i\}_{i=1}^n$ be the random variables which indicate if the $i-th$ letter is $s$ or not. (Bernouli independent random variables with success probability $1/k$) Let also $N_{s-1}$ is the random variable which counts how many times the letters $\{1,\dots,s-1\}$ appear in a given random word. Then the LHS is exactly $$P(\sum_{i=1}^nX_i \geq p )$$ while the RHS is smaller than
$$ P(\sum_{i=1}^{n-N_{s-1}}X_i\geq p| N_{s-1}\geq (s-1)p),$$
which is clearly smaller.

Comment: (i) Your latter probability is undefined, because you have not defined the joint distribution of $N_{s-1}$ and the $X_i$'s. (ii) How come the definition of $N_{s-1}$ does not involve $p$? (iii) The success probability should be $1/k$, not $1/n$.

Comment: @IosifPinelis Thanks for the comments, now I think it is correct.

Comment: Now I don't see any reasons for your main claims: (i) "the RHS is smaller than" and (ii) "which is clearly smaller".

Comment: the first smaller than is because since you assume that each of the s-1 first letters appears at least p times, this is less likely than the fact that all the first s-1 all together appear (s-1)p times. The second less than is because you sum less things.

Comment: (i) concerning ""the RHS is smaller than": it seems your logic here is that, if $P(B)\le P(C)$, then $P(A|B)\le P(A|C)$. However, this is false in general, even if you assume that $B\subset C$. (ii) concerning  "which is clearly smaller": you seem to assume there that the joint distribution of the $X_i$'s is not affected by the condition $N_{s-1}\ge(s-1)p$, which does not seem to be the case.

Comment: You are right, I understand your objection. But now I'm curious, it should be true (or not ?) that (with the notation in your answer) $P(N_s \geq p | N_{s-1}\geq p, \dots N_1 \geq p ) \leq P( N_s \geq p | n-N_s \geq (s-1)p ),$ which is what I claimed. Is there a straight forward proof of this? I guess writing down the formulas ?

Comment: I don't know whether the inequality in your latest comment is true, and I also don't know whether it is relevant to the OP question.